# Unir dos datos de dos tablas diferentes Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

quisiera saber como hacer una consulta que tenga datos en un solo campo de dos tablas diferentes en Mysql.

Tabla 1:

```
SELECT cto_email1 FROM contactos
```

Tabla 2:

```
SELECT correo FROM usuarios
```

Como se puede ver, ambos tienen los campos de correos, pero los campos se llaman diferentes.

Lo que quiero es que en el resultado se vea todos sus datos en un solo campo combinado.

Ejemplo:

correo1 
correo2 
correo3 
correo4 
correo5 
correo6 
correo7 
correo8

Y así de las dos tablas...

Comment: Bienvenido Alex Gallardo a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Prueba buscando y tratando con `UNION`

Answer (score 1):

es un poco tarde quizá, respecto de la fecha que publicaste, pero daré solución a tu pregunta, quizá le sirva a alguien.
Bien, para poder hacer lo que tu quieres, se puede hacer uso de UNION, UNION ALL, etc.
Puedes usar un ALIAS, en el primer SELECT para que ese sea el valor temporal de la columna, (EL ALIAS se pone asi: columnaNombre AS NOMBRE), ahora pasaré a lo práctico para que veas como se hace:

```
SELECT cto_email1 AS CORREOS FROM contactos
UNION
SELECT correo AS CORREOS FROM usuarios;
```

Y listo, con eso queda solventado tu problema, la salida sería:

| CORREOS |
| --- |
| Correo 1 |
| Correo 2 |
| Correo 3 |

Comment: ¿Funcionaría si el alias para la primera columna es _correos_ y no _correo_?

Comment: @padaleiana de hecho las dos columnas "cto_email1" y "correo" deben llevar el mismo alias por orden solamente (ten en cuenta que el ALIAS, es el nombre que tú libremente decides darle a una columna y éste es solamente un nombre temporal), eso sí, si tu columna lleva un nombre con espacios, debes ponerlo entre comillas, de lo contrario dará error: por ej. si quieres que tu columna se llame lista correos, debes hacerlo así: SELECT cto_email1 AS 'LISTA CORREOS' FROM contactos y listo, aunque ésto último no es recomendable hacerlo, al menos por buenas prácticas no es viable.

Comment: Justamente por eso hacía la pregunta, para corregir el typo :) Y concuerdo en que en lo posible hay que evitar usar espacios en blanco en alias (y en nombres de columna incluso).